# Run Device Emulator 3.0 (WM6.5) in Windows XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, device-emulation, xp-mode

Is it possible to run Windows XP Mode within Windows 7, install Visual Studio 2008, and use Device Emulator 3.0 (using a Windows Mobile 6.5 image)?  So far, I can get the image to run, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the network to work properly.

Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/microsoftdeviceemu/thread/ec9ea2bd-c216-4205-aaa3-fb96602efb6b/

I stopped at step 15.

I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I also did this:
http://www.brianpeek.com/blog/archive/2009/05/02/windows-virtual-pc-and-the-microsoft-device-emulator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Virtual Machine 2007?

This is required for the network to work on the emulator.

Comment: Yes.  I have installed Virtual PC 2007 SP1 in Windows XP Mode, along with ActiveSync 4.5 and all the images.

Comment: No.  I'm just unable to obtain an IP or get any thruput.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing ActiveSync and using the "Cradle" feature in the device emulator manager

Comment: That seems to allow me access to the internet, but for some reason, it wouldn't allow me to access internal IPs.

Comment: Try setting ActiveSync to connect to the "Work Network", instead of "Internet"